# Empty object when using DTO with multipart/form-data on NestJS

Tags: nestjs, multipartform-data, multer, dto

In my backend, I have this endpoint:

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
create(
  @UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
  @Body() body: MyDto,
  ) {
  console.log(body);
  console.log(files);
}
```

`MyDto` is as simple as:

```
export class MyDto {

  year: string
}
```

When I send a `multipart/form-data` request (tried with code on Firefox, Chrome and with Postman) only with the `year` field or together with one or more files, I get this from the first `console.log` (the one that prints the `body`):

```
MyDto {}
```

When I remove the typing from the body and the endpoint becomes:

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
create(
  @UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
  @Body() body,
  ) {
  console.log(body);
  console.log(files);
}
```

The body is shown as:

```
[Object: null prototype] { year: '2022' }
```

The `files` variable is always correct.
How can I set the type for the body?

My `main.ts` is as follows:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: ['log', 'error'],
  });
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '1mb', extended: true}));
  const appVersion = '0.0.1';
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  await app.listen(port);
```

Comment: (not related to the question) you need to disable the builtin json parser if you want to enable that custom one: add `bodyParser: false` to `NestFactory.create` options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing any decorator on the `year` property of the `MyDto` class, and because you have `whitelist: true`, `class-validator` will strip the non-whitelisted values (i.e. the values that don't match up with a decorated property of the class)

Comment: another option is to use `@Allow` decorator on a property to bypass validation.